# How to permanently change dns for ubuntu18/20 in systemd-resolved

Tags: dns, system, ubuntu-18.04

I try to change dns for ubuntu18。

first I try modify the confg file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`  to

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
DNS=10.40.127.38
LLMNR=no
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=no-negative
#ddDNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

and then, I try `systemctl restart systemd-resolved`

I found no change when I checked the dns. During the investigation, I executed`systemd-resolve --status`

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
  Current DNS Server: 10.40.127.38        
         DNS Servers: 10.40.127.38        
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 2 (enp0s3)
      Current Scopes: DNS           
DefaultRoute setting: yes           
       LLMNR setting: yes           
MulticastDNS setting: no            
  DNSOverTLS setting: no            
      DNSSEC setting: no            
    DNSSEC supported: no            
  Current DNS Server: 10.40.30.5    
         DNS Servers: 10.40.30.5    
                      10.0.2.2      
          DNS Domain: ~.            
                      test.com
```

So what I am modifying is only global dns, how should I modify the dns of enp0s3 network card?

I searched and found that netplan can be modified, but is there another way?

Thanks a lot for answering～

Answer (score 2):

The DNS stub file contains the local stub 127.0.0.53 as the only DNS server, and it is redirected to the /etc/resolv.conf file which was used to add the name servers used by the system.

If you run the following ls command on the /etc/resolv.conf, you will see that this file is a symlink to the /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf file.

So,

- open the /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head configuration file.
- and add the following lines in it:

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

[Set Permanent DNS Name Servers in Resolvconf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeE6f.png)

Save the changes and restart the resolvconf.service or reboot the system.

$ sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service

Now when you check the /etc/resolv.conf file, the name server entries should be stored there permanently. Henceforth, you will not face any issues concerning name resolution on your system.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRXqv.png)

Comment: Beware that you will not be able to resolve LAN domains using this approach (obvoiusly, but anyways worth to mention)

Comment: I need to `sudo apt install resolvconf` first to have that directory and `sudo resolvconf -u` to take effect immediately,  see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128223/64403)